# CodeIgniter - unable to load requested class

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoload

Yes, I imagine you are thinking to say that this question is a possible duplicate, however it isn't as the answers for the similar questions do not fix the issue I am currently having.

I'm receiving the following error while autoloading a library named 'phpass' as follows.

> An Error Was Encountered
>   Unable to load the requested class: Phpass

Code to autoload the library

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'phpass');
```

The phpass.php file resides in the application/libraries folder, and the class is declared as `class phpass` meaning that the issue cannot be related to capitalisation or the file path as suggested in the majority of other answers I have come across.

Please can you tell me what I am missing? It works perfectly in MAMP, however, when uploading to my Linux Ubuntu server (Apache2), it stops working.

Thanks,

Max.

Edit--- Constructor method as requested by Utku

```
class phpass {

    protected $PasswordHash;

    // default values if config was not found
    protected $iteration_count_log2 = 8;
    protected $portable_hashes = FALSE;

    /**
     * Construct with configuration array
     * 
     * @param array $config
     */
    public function __construct($config = array()) {
        // check if the original phpass file exists
        if (!file_exists($path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../vendor/PasswordHash.php')) {
            show_error('The phpass class file was not found.');
        }

        include ($path);

        if (!empty($config)) {
            $this->initialize($config);
        }

        // create phpass object
        $this->PasswordHash = new PasswordHash($this->iteration_count_log2, $this->portable_hashes);
    }
```

Comment: Linux is case sensitive, windows not, are you use its class name "phpass" not "Phpass"

Comment: I ruled out the error being as a result of the filename, and I'm running on Mac, not windows, hence using MAMP not WAMP.

Comment: Error tells us its looking for "Phpass" not phpass

Comment: Yes, but it's not possible considering the code I am using. I'm not calling `Phpass` anywhere in my code, only `phpass`

Comment: can you paste first lines of phpass.php file where its contructor visible

Comment: I've updated the question with the constructor.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think the capitalisation of your file name and class name is the issue, according to the [user guide](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html):

- `phppass.php` should be `Phppass.php`
- `class phpass` should be `class Phpass`

Comment: No problem at all @max_! I'm glad this helped!